# Chrome 39 redirects randomly

Tags: google-chrome, redirect

i have a very troubleing issue!

Since the new update with chrome (39) my browser starts to redirect randomly. Meaning that some files are being loaded even if i am on another page. For instance i have the following `button`:

```
 <button onclick="location.href='/Clients/index'" class="btn btn-success" style="float: right;">Færdig</button>
```

When this is clicked the page is loaded correctly however another page is loaded right after: `/Modules/testComplete` which was the previous page i was on.

Apprently it seems like a pattern that the previous page is being called right after (or before hard to tell) the new page is loaded.

I found the following post: [Chrome redirects randomly](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Q74jiLWfLdM%5B1-25-false%5D)

And it seems to be a problem with chrome version (39).

I tested it with chrome version (35) and found no issues. But the problem is that my clients use the newest version of chrome so does anyone know how to fix this?